# Changing the position of a CSS element (A decorative curly brace from left to right)

Tags: html, css

I am just starting to learn HTML, CSS and web coding! I found this example of a CSS curly brace element, where the curly brace ({) comes to the left of the content. What I want to do is switch that around so that it would be on the right hand side of the content and the opposite curly brace (}).

Could somebody point me in the right direction as to how I might achieve that?!

Thanks for any help provided

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' class=''>
    <head>
        <style class="cp-pen-styles">
            .curly-braced-block {
              position: relative;
              margin: 20px 0;
            }
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left {
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              float: left;
              width: 20px;
              height: 100%;
              position: absolute;
            }
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left .brace-top,
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left .brace-bottom {
              position: absolute;
              width: 10px;
              height: 50%;
              left: 10px;
            }
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left .brace-top {
              top: 0;
            }
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left .brace-bottom {
              top: 50%;
            }
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left .brace-top:before,
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left .brace-top:after,
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left .brace-bottom:before,
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left .brace-bottom:after {
              content: "";
              height: 50%;
              width: 10px;
              display: block;
              position: absolute;
            }
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left .brace-top:before {
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              border-left: 3px solid black;
              -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
              -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
              border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            }
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left .brace-top:after {
              bottom: 0;
              left: -10px;
              border-right: 3px solid black;
              -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
              -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
              border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
            }
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left .brace-bottom:before {
              top: 0;
              left: -10px;
              border-right: 3px solid black;
              -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
              -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
              border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            }
            .curly-braced-block .brace-left .brace-bottom:after {
              bottom: 0;
              left: 0;
              border-left: 3px solid black;
              -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
              -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
              border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            }
            .curly-braced-block .content {
              text-align: left;
              margin-left: 25px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="curly-braced-block">
      <div class="brace-left">
        <div class="brace-top"></div>
        <div class="brace-bottom"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et fermentum metus. Proin eget euismod dui. Mauris consectetur ipsum orci, nec iaculis odio ullamcorper sit amet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla imperdiet, ligula sed dignissim lobortis,
        ligula turpis venenatis sem, ac luctus enim leo quis ipsum. In id mollis risus. Vivamus auctor arcu nec blandit cursus. Vestibulum hendrerit suscipit tellus at luctus. Duis convallis libero sit amet nulla lobortis aliquam. Nullam sodales facilisis
        massa, sed semper velit semper in. Nulla congue aliquam felis ac fringilla.s venenatis sem, ac luctus enim leo quis ipsum. In id mollis risus. Vivamus auctor arcu nec blandit cursus. Vestibulum hendrerit suscipit tellus at luctus. Duis convallis libero sit amet nulla lobortis aliquam. Nullam sodales facilisis
        massa, sed semper velit semper in. Nulla congue aliquam felis ac fringilla.
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create the `.brace-right` class by swapping right with left in the css.

Then, in the HTML, just change `class="brace-left"` with `class="brace-right"`

```css
.curly-braced-block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.curly-braced-block .brace-right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.curly-braced-block .brace-right .brace-top,
.curly-braced-block .brace-right .brace-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  right: 10px;
}
.curly-braced-block .brace-right .brace-top {
  top: 0;
}
.curly-braced-block .brace-right .brace-bottom {
  top: 50%;
}
.curly-braced-block .brace-right .brace-top:before,
.curly-braced-block .brace-right .brace-top:after,
.curly-braced-block .brace-right .brace-bottom:before,
.curly-braced-block .brace-right .brace-bottom:after {
  content: "";
  height: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.curly-braced-block .brace-right .brace-top:before {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.curly-braced-block .brace-right .brace-top:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -10px;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.curly-braced-block .brace-right .brace-bottom:before {
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
.curly-braced-block .brace-right .brace-bottom:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.curly-braced-block .content {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' class=''>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="curly-braced-block">
      <div class="brace-right">
        <div class="brace-top"></div>
        <div class="brace-bottom"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et fermentum metus. Proin eget euismod dui. Mauris consectetur ipsum orci, nec iaculis odio ullamcorper sit amet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla imperdiet, ligula sed dignissim lobortis,
        ligula turpis venenatis sem, ac luctus enim leo quis ipsum. In id mollis risus. Vivamus auctor arcu nec blandit cursus. Vestibulum hendrerit suscipit tellus at luctus. Duis convallis libero sit amet nulla lobortis aliquam. Nullam sodales facilisis
        massa, sed semper velit semper in. Nulla congue aliquam felis ac fringilla.s venenatis sem, ac luctus enim leo quis ipsum. In id mollis risus. Vivamus auctor arcu nec blandit cursus. Vestibulum hendrerit suscipit tellus at luctus. Duis convallis libero sit amet nulla lobortis aliquam. Nullam sodales facilisis
        massa, sed semper velit semper in. Nulla congue aliquam felis ac fringilla.
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```